# How to print a CCK image field alt text in a node template?

Tags: nodes, theming, entities, media

I'm trying to add the alt text from a cck image field in a Drupal 7 node template.  Getting the image style url is done, but I can't figure out how to just get the alt text.  This is what I have

```
<img src="<?php print image_style_url('160x160', $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" alt="????" class="thumbnail" />
```

How does one just output the alt text?

Comment: does a `print_r($node->field_image, TRUE)` or its equivalent shed any light on it?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), you'll be able to use:

```
<?php dpm($node); ?>
```

It will provide all available fields that you could use. Another method might be to use [`theme('image')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) to help clean up your image theming.

Answer (score 0):

A print_r will give you idea. In your case it will be

```
$node->field_image['und'][0]['alt']
```

ie: `<img src="<?php print image_style_url('160x160', $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $node->field_image['und'][0]['alt']; ?>" class="thumbnail" />`